# Graphite agent names

Tags: graphite, sensu, graphite-carbon

I have setup sensu with graphite following this:
https://blog.powerupcloud.com/step-by-step-install-and-configure-sensu-grafana-9cedca333396.
Everything seems to be setup correctly but When I go the graphite website the agent names are shown as cryptic Ids rather than what I defined in `client.json`.
Am I missing something here?

I am also not seeing custom metrics data in graphite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphite will use the server hostname as agent ID. If you need to change the graphite agent names, Please change the hostname of the server. Whatever you are keeping names in **client.json** will display in uchiwa console.

Which type of custom metrics you are using?

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. It was a problem with our relay.json file and client subscription. The cryptic name was correctly appearing as our host had a cryptic name . Fixing client.json and relay.json and restarting the sensu api worked.